# how to change height to drop down box in html?

Tags: html, css

The problem is I can't change the height of the drop down box in html.for (select->option) I try to apply the style in CSS. It does not works

Comment: You should share some code here.

Comment: he is asking to change the height of the 'option' not the select tag

Comment: yes i want to change the height of the 'option'

Answer (score 5):

You can not control the style of `option`. (see here:https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/)

however you can change the `font-size` and the `option` will grow

```css
select option{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change height of 'option'

Only you can change the background-color and color of the 'option' values

You can change the 'select' element height.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `height` CSS attribute for the `select` tag.

```css
label select {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <select>
        <option selected>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
        <option>Option 4</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Comment: I dont think this is the required answer. The dropdown menu needs to be increased in height

Comment: I want to change the height of the option not select

Comment: @Abishek you can use
`select option{
 height: 100px;
}`
and also you can use overflow propety for option which makes it scrollable

Answer (score -1):

```
<select style="min-height:40px;min-width:100px;">
     <option value="">Select1</option>
     <option value="">Select2</option>
     <option value="">Select3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can style the *select* and *option* elements usign CSS like this:

`select {
    height: 200px;
    color: red;
}`

`option {
    color: green;
}`

Notice that you have to remove the "." before *select* and *option*.
This will overwrite any *select* and *option* element.

EDIT:

You can also refer to a certain *select* element by giving to that element a class name, like this:

`select.s1{
    height: 100px;
}`

`select.s2{
    height: 150px;
}`

```
<select class="s1">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select class="s2">
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
    <option value="alfaromeo>Alfa Romeo</option>
    <option value="lancia">Lancia</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you example, doesn't work with option , it s a bad example